# How to design a many to many relation across multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am creating a web app using ef core, and I have three entites, `Student`, `Teacher`, and `Project`. Now each of these tables needs to have multiple `Link`s (Id & Url columns here) that point somewhere on the web. What is the best way to design this relation.

I've thought adding a StudentId, TeacherId, and ProjectId nullable column to the Links table. I've thought of creating a Links table for each entity. I've also thought of using a discriminator column, but still, it doesn't feel right.

How do I properly design this?

Note: The Student and Teacher table have a one to one relation with a user table, so I could just put the foreign key there, but the Project table is unrelated to these.

Comment: Is any of the link "entities" releated more than one of any of your other entities? If not, and each link is unique (or at least not shared), why do you want to have them separated from the entity it is related to? The only reason you might want to separate an attribute is when it is sparse. For this case there is special solution provided by SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Just because two entities share the same shape, doesn't make them the same entitiy.  It's fine to have a StudentLink entity and a ProjectLink entity.  They may have the same properties initially.

Comment: @ZorgoZ each Student, Teacher, and Project has multiple Links, but a Link can only have one of the previous 3. I didn't really understand your suggestion, could you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes, I am currently going with that design. Still thought there might be a better way to this, but it seems this is the best I've got.

Comment: This problem is known as *polymorphic associations*. Once you know this term you'll notice that there are many posts on this issue.

Comment: @GertArnold yes I've read a lot on this, I think EF Core still only supports TPH. So I think I'll just create a concrete Link table for each entity.

Comment: Concrete Link table for each entity is the only sensible design for this pattern. (And do I ever wish I'd known that a couple of years ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments the link, you have a set of links for some or each of your entities in question.

But these are attributes, even a link array is an attribute of those entities, as a link is not an entity on its own. Unfortunately, 1NF requires each attribute to have a unique value. But let's be serious: is this an unbreakable constraint? Of course not. Some RDBMS do have array columns. SQL Server does not. But it has XML and JSON column types. EF has some other tools to provide the same.

Actually it depends on what do you want to do with those links: are they somehow processed with SQL or not. If only the upper tiers are handling them - and I suppose they are processed on the visualization tier - from the database point of view the link array is a single attribute.

If those links are passing trough your business logic, and they are only used during rendering, you can simply store them as comma-separated lists, or JSONS text in a `nvarchar` with a string property counterpart in the EF entity class, and split/parse them only on the visualization tier. That would make the less concentrated effort.

If your business logic needs them separately, EF does have support for complex types. You can still store your arrays as JSON text in a `nvarchar` column and serialize-deserialize them transparently. Check here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1166099/Entity-Framework-Storing-complex-properties-as-JSO even better solution here: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/14779740/can-i-embed-an-object-in-an-ef-entity--serialize-on-save--deserialize-on-access--

`SPARSE` is still there of course, if applicable.

Comment: I think you asked a question I've missed. Actually yes, those links are purely for rendering purposes, and as such, it's probably best to store them on a nvarchar field as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below three mapping tables. Which are maintain your many to many relationship.

Like: 4 to 5 students working on same link.
2 teachers handling same link.

```
create table student_link_mapping(slmid int identity(1,1), studentid int not null, linkid int not null)

create table teacher_link_mapping(tlmid int identity(1,1), teacherid int not null, linkid int not null)

create table project_link_mapping(plmid int identity(1,1), projectid int not null, linkid int not null)
```

Comment: The problem is not linking teachers/students to projects. It's linking teachers/students/projects to the links table. Where those 3 have multiple links, but a link can only have one of the previous 3.

Comment: Just edited answer. Let me know it is working for you.